# How do I export Daz3D characters into an XNA format?

Tags: xna, 3d, character

How do I export 3D animated characters created in Daz3D studio to a format suitable for inclusion in XNA video games?  I'm looking for instructions on how to make sure weight, bones, vertices and materials are properly translated over into an XNA useable format.

Comment: I have never used Daz3D so I can't give you any detailed instructions. But .fbx is the format you want to export.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FBX-Koverter. XNA can read fbx.